# How to remove the blank page from the middle

Tags: bibliographies, incompatibility

I need a help that first i add the `bibfile` for the bibliography but later on I done the `bibliograpbhy` with simple way. The problem is that a blank page is appear due to that `bibfile` and after the bibliography appear which was done in a simple way. So I remove that blank page I tried a lot of this like `\cleardoublepage` and so many code so what i will do.

That is my mainfile after remove the \biliography{Bibliraphy} means bibfile.

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\doublespacing
%------------
\include{main pages/ch1}
\include{main pages/ch2}
\include{main pages/ch3}
\include{main pages/ch4}
\include{main pages/ch5}
\appendix
\include{main pages/app1}
\chapter*{}
\begin{thebibliography}{102}
\bibitem{1}K. Chandel et al., “Midgut microbial community of \textit{Culex.quinquefasciatus} mosquito populations from India,” \emph{PLoS One}, vol. 8, no. 11, 2013, doi:  10.1371/journal.pone.0080453.
\bibitem{2}E. Nchoutpouen et al., “\textit{Culex} species diversity, susceptibility to insecticides and role as potential vector of Lymphatic filariasis in the city of Yaoundé, Cameroon,”\emph{ PLoS Negl. Trop. Dis.}, vol. 13, no. 4, pp. 1–16, 2019, doi: 10.1371/journal.pntd.0007229.
\bibitem{3}S. Bhattacharya, P. Basu, and C. Sajal Bhattacharya, “The Southern House Mosquito, \textit{Culex quinquefasciatus}: profile of a smart vector,” \emph{J. Entomol. Zool. Stud. JEZS}, vol. 73, no. 42, pp. 73–81, 2016.
\end{thebibliography}
```

[image]

Comment: still its not working the blank page is not removed even I am using this code   \begingroup
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\bibliography{Bibliography.bib}
\endgroup
  Can i delete that bibliography.bib tex file from the main file.

Comment: anyone please reply my question?

Comment: Since you’re using a manual bibliography you need to put the group before the `\chapter*`.

Comment: This is the way I write it but still it not working.\include{main pages/ch1}
\include{main pages/ch2}
\include{main pages/ch3}
\include{main pages/ch4}
\include{main pages/ch5}
\appendix
\include{main pages/app1}
\begingroup
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\bibliography{Bibliography.bib}
\endgroup

\chapter*{}
\begin{thebibliography}{102}
\end{thebiliography}

Comment: please kindly help me to remove that blank page.

Comment: The `\endgroup` must go after  `\end{bibliography}`. Also, have you tried just adding `openany` as a documentclass option (with no extra code)? That should also work.

Comment: \documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, openright]{report} this is my docunment class

Comment: Right, change `openright` to `openany`.

Comment: Still it's not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119565/discussion-between-mona-ishtiaq-and-alan-munn).

Comment: How we add a color in table of content in latex???